# OleDbException Too many fields defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbdataadapter

I am using asp.net.

**GetTable method**

```
 private DataSet GetTable(string pathUrl, string extention)
        {
            string path= pathUrl;
            string strConn;
            if (extention == "xls")
                strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path+ ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            else strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path+ ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";


            OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + GetExcelSheetNames(path, extention)[0] + "]", strConn);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            myCommand.Fill(myDataSet, "ExcelInfo"); // I get error here
            if (myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return myDataSet;
            }
            else return null;
        }
```

**GetExcellSheetNames Method**

```
static String[] GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFile, string extention)
        {
            OleDbConnection objConn = null;
            System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
            string path = excelFile;
            string Conn = "";
            if (extention == "xls")
                Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            else Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
            try
            {    
                objConn = new OleDbConnection(Conn);
                objConn.Open();

                dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                if (dt == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                int i = 0;


                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    i++;
                }

                return excelSheets;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (objConn != null)
                {
                    objConn.Close();
                    objConn.Dispose();
                }
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    dt.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Error is exactly at:**

I get error below code In **GetTable method**

```
myCommand.Fill(myDataSet, "ExcelInfo");
```

**Exception Details:**

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Too many fields defined.
```

**Question:**

myCommand.Fill(myDataSet, "ExcelInfo"); displays error because of column number in **excell** file .I researched about this and **people says columns must not be more than 255** columns etc.

So

If i try to select 50 column i can not do this because column name are not same.How can i solve this problem , i do not have any idea.I am so confused about changing select query because this code works however not works more columns number.

Any help apreciates.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value value of `GetExcelSheetNames(path, extention)[0]` exactly and how many column are there?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

You missed "$" after Sheet name.

> OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" +
>   GetExcelSheetNames(path, extention)[0] + "**$**]", strConn);